# How can i use MysqlDB model in python 3.3?

Tags: python, mysql-python, python-3.3

when i run Django1.5 in python3.3,It report a problem say that no Model named MySQLdb.So how can i install MySQLdb on python 3.3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official MySQLdb doesn't have Python 3 support, try installing [MySQL-for-Python](https://github.com/clelland/MySQL-for-Python-3) instead.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose the package at [MySQL Python 3](https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3) to be compatible, you might give it a try. OR

[PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL), a pure python client library without a dependency on the standard mysql client library, has Python 3 support via a build script.